# React JS to loop over text and apply effects error

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dependencies, refactoring

I am trying to load a page in react JS and the title loops over 3 entries from an object. I want the titles from the object to fade in and out. So I have created four functions called fadeIn, stationary, fadeOut and updateTitle. These call each other with a timeout.

I have got this to work but am not sure if its the most efficient code. Also, I am getting an error for a dependency:

`React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'items.length'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Firstly, how should I fix the warning? Furthermore, any suggestions for refactoring?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react' 
function TextLoop() {

 const [items] = useState([
{ title: 'A Content Creator.' },
{ title: 'A Designer.' },
{ title: 'An Engineer.' }]
);

const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
const [flickerTitle, setFlickerTitle] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
const fadeIn = () => {
  let timer = setTimeout(() => {
    setFlickerTitle({
      display: "inline",
      opacity: "1",
      transition: "opacity 2s"
    })
    stationary();
  }, 0)
  return () => { clearTimeout(timer) }
}
const stationary = () => {
  let timer = setTimeout(() => {
    setFlickerTitle({
      display: "inline",
      opacity: "1",
    })
    fadeOut();
  }, 2500)
  return () => { clearTimeout(timer) }
}
const fadeOut = () => {
  let timer = setTimeout(() => {
    setFlickerTitle({
      display: "inline",
      opacity: "0",
      transition: "opacity 2s"
    })
    updateTitle();
  }, 2500)
  return () => { clearTimeout(timer) }
}
const updateTitle = () => {
  let timer = setTimeout(() => {
    setIndex((state) => (state + 1) % items.length);
    fadeIn();
  }, 3000)
  return () => { clearTimeout(timer) }
}
fadeIn();
  }, []
);
return (
  <div style={flickerTitle}>
    {items[index].title}
  </div>
 )
}

export default TextLoop;
```

Comment: The dependencies param of ```useEffect``` is an empty array in your code but react found out that when ```items.length``` changes the ```useEffect``` callback must be called so you should pass it in that array to get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Try using react-animated CSS, just wrap your content to avoid that code.

```
import {Animated} from "react-animated-css";


<Animated animationIn="bounceInLeft" animationOut="fadeOut" isVisible={true}>
    <div>
        hello world
    </div>
</Animated>
```